# > < key recognized as right ctrl key

Tags: keyboard, kde, hp, 22.04

My Kubuntu 22.04 Installation is recognizing the <kbd>< ></kbd> key as <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> key. Because of this, I cannot do any HTML, which I really need to. This issue also occurs on normal Ubuntu, and also on 21.10.

I have an HP 14s laptop which has a German layout, and the <kbd>< ></kbd> key is on the right side of the spacebar. Here is a photo of this:

[image: HP Tastatur Layout]

<sup>HP Tastatur Layout</sup>

I have checked the language layout, as well as the Keyboard Model. At The Moment i am using the Generic 102-Key Keyboard, but I have tried 90% of ALL the other layouts and they didn't help.

Here is another Photo when I press the key, what KDE shows what key is recognized:

[image: KDE Layout Inspector]

<sup>KDE Layout Inspector</sup>

Any help getting my <kbd>< ></kbd> key back would be very appreciated!

Comment: check the shortcuts menu in the system settings for < and >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, as I do not have a keyboard similar to yours to test with. However, based on [a similar issue reported on an HP forum](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/The-greater-than-less-than-signs-quot-lt-quot-and-quot-gt/m-p/6800297/highlight/true#M249759), there may be an error within the keyboard hardware itself that sends the wrong control code when pressing the <kbd>< ></kbd> key.

The gist of the solution comes down to remapping `E0_1D` to `00_56`, which is an "ISO Extra" key. The solution on the HP site is Windows-specific, but you should be able to do something similar using Tobi's [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper). This tool works with both X11 and Wayland, so there should be no issues on your machine, and you can grab a `.deb` [from the release page](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/releases).

If you would like to quickly install this from the Terminal, you can do so like:

```
wget https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/releases/download/1.4.2/input-remapper-1.4.2.deb
sudo dpkg -i input-remapper-1.4.2.deb
```

With this tool, you should be able to replace the erroneous <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd> with something that works.